# Rename tag "full-metal-alchemist" to "fullmetal-alchemist"

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags

(Shog9 [said in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/7248274#7248274) that such tag rename requests should be made in meta, so here's the first one)

...I don't know what else to say though. All official sources (both English and Japanese) show that the title is two words, not three.

Comment: That's my fault, sorry, I posted the first question about it, and everybody just used my tag.

Comment: @Danalog Not blaming anyone, I just think it's best to fix this now rather than when there are a lot more questions and users. :)

Comment: I agree. I just finished editing an answer to a question related to Fullmetal Alchemist and changed a few occurrences of "Full Metal" to "Fullmetal", as the latter is the correct combination of those two words for the official English title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Performed a simple rename for this. Did not elect to setup a synonym yet, but in this case it's not unreasonable. I imagine the most of people will use Fullmetal but it's feasible to expect someone (especially someone brand new) might look up for Full Metal.

Comment: Shouldn't need a synonym - IIRC, if you try to create a tag that differs from an existing tag only by dashes, it'll be blocked.