# More tag hyphen shenanigans: [sekaiichi-hatsukoi] to [sekai-ichi-hatsukoi]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

[sekaiichi-hatsukoi](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sekaiichi-hatsukoi) to [sekai-ichi-hatsukoi](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sekai-ichi-hatsukoi), please.

cf.:

- [Crunchyroll](http://www.crunchyroll.com/sekai-ichi-hatsukoi-worlds-greatest-first-love) calls it "Sekai Ichi Hatsukoi" (plus a subtitle)
- the official websites are http://sekai-ichi.jp/ and http://sekai-ichi-movie.jp/

Comment: tho [MAL](http://myanimelist.net/anime/9926/Sekaiichi_Hatsukoi) says "Sekaiichi Hatsukoi" and *Synonyms: Sekai-ichi Hatsukoi, Sekai'ichi Hatsukoi*

Comment: @user1306322 True, but MAL is also not an authoritative source by any measure.