# Hyphenation change request for JoJo tag

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed, tags, retagging

For internal consistency's sake, [jojo-no-kimyouna-bouken](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jojo-no-kimyouna-bouken) should be either [jojono-kimyouna-bouken](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jojono-kimyouna-bouken) or [jojo-no-kimyou-na-bouken](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jojo-no-kimyou-na-bouken). The latter is obviously preferable, since that's how we pretty much always treat particles (i.e. as being space-separated from the word that precedes them).

So, [jojo-no-kimyouna-bouken](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jojo-no-kimyouna-bouken) → [jojo-no-kimyou-na-bouken](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jojo-no-kimyou-na-bouken), please. Don't worry - the extra `-` only bring it to 24 characters.

Comment: For consistency, we really need to revisit the prioritization of English tags vs romanized Japanese tags. We're primarily an English language site. So we should prioritize the English series names over the non-English ones when an official title is made available and synonymize the other non-English versions. SEO wise the romanized Japanese tags would probably have better visibility due to factors such as age. While the effort to keep our tag grammatically correct is appreciate, I don't believe that minor tag changes would have significant impact on the searchability of content on our site.

Comment: @ʞɹɐzǝɹ I mean, sure, it won't have a significant impact, but it still bugs me!

Comment: Instead, I think we should take a moment and look at who we think our target audience is currently and how we want to go from there.

Comment: @ʞɹɐzǝɹ Anyway, that is probably a discussion for a separate post, but the heuristic we should be working off is "what title is best known by English speakers?". For JoJo, this should probably be `jojos-bizarre-adventure`, but for other shows like Nichijou, `nichijou` is clearly superior to `my-ordinary-life`.