# Can't edit tag to contain hyphens

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

A question got posted with a tag without any hyphens between words and it turns out one can't just edit it:

> [image]

Since when? And please somebody fix that tag.

Comment: At least the tag has been fixed (thanks, Senshin!)

Comment: [Related (unanswered) Meta.SE question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/193732).

Comment: This is a known pain-in-the-butt: see http://meta.anime.stackexchange.com/q/966/ and http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/234309/. Whenever you see this happen, please cast an "in need of moderator intervention" flag, and one of us will re-hyphenate the tag appropriately.