# Make [occulticnine] be the synonymy of [occultic-nine]

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags

so i came across [this question](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/37137/1587) seeing [retag](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/retag) and figure i create the tags. as i was about to add [occultic-nine](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/occultic-nine) i noticed that [occulticnine](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/occulticnine) already existsed but must5 have been orphaned as there was no questions to it.

when i tried to create [occultic-nine](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/occultic-nine) to match with other tages like [steins-gate](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/steins-gate), [chaos-head](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chaos-head) and [robotics-notes](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/robotics-notes) which used the same naming structure as the others (*Occultic;Nine*, *Steins;Gate*, *Chaos;Head*, *Robotics;Notes*) i got this

[image: error]

I would like to request that [occulticnine](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/occulticnine) be made a synonym of [occultic-nine](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/occultic-nine) so that [occultic-nine](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/occultic-nine) is used instead.

Also i would like to know why i got this error. yes the error explains the problem however [occulticnine](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/occulticnine) had no questions to it (or atleast they weren't appearing when i searched the tag) so it shouldn't be giving me problems to begin with

Comment: Apologies for the confusion. I thought that an occultic-nine tag would be better than occulticnine since they're two words (and the other tags in the science adventure series are hyphenated)

Comment: @Vermonus No harm done. One of us would've come through and fixed it in short order if you hadn't anyway.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I would like to request that occulticnine be made a synonym of occultic-nine so that occultic-nine is used instead.

[Krazer fixed it](https://anime.stackexchange.com/revisions/37137/5). Hooray!

(He didn't make it a synonym, though. There's no point in having tags that differ only by hyphens be made synonyms of one another, since the tag autocompleter will find the tag either way.)

> Also i would like to know why i got this error. yes the error explains the problem however occulticnine had no questions to it (or atleast they weren't appearing when i searched the tag) so it shouldn't be giving me problems to begin with

In [revision 2](https://anime.stackexchange.com/revisions/37137/2) of the same question, Arcane created the tag [occulticnine]. The OP then changed it back to [retag], which is why no questions with [occulticnine] showed up in search for you. The zero-use-tag-deleter will get rid of [occulticnine] when it runs in a few hours, but for now [occulticnine] still lives.

Comment: Krazer also pointed me to [this](http://meta.anime.stackexchange.com/questions/966/fixing-tag-hyphenation-issues-shouldnt-be-so-hard) in the chat showing why he was able to fix it and not me